# ruby-opencv IplImageオブジェクト作成時にエラー NULL array pointer is passed in function cvGetMat

Tags: ruby, opencv

ruby-opencvでIplImageオブジェクトを作成する次のコードでエラーが発生します。

```
def self.make_cv_object_from_url(url)
  image = nil

  open(url) do |image_data|
    image = IplImage.decode_image(image_data.read)
  end

  image
end
```

エラーはデバガを使った所、`decode_image`の部分で起こっているようです。
`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /tmp/opencv20160107-29960-t5glvv/opencv-2.4.12/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2382: error: (-27) NULL array pointer is passed in function cvGetMat`

いろいろな関数でIplImageオブジェクトを作成するためにこのコードを利用していますが、特定の関数で利用した時のみ、上記エラーが発生し原因がわからず困っています。

環境
Capitan 10.11.3
Ruby ruby 2.2.3
Opencv 2.4.12
ruby-opencv 0.0.14

どなたか解決方法わかる方いましたらご教授お願いします。

Comment: `image_data.read` に失敗しているというか、結果がnilや空になっているような気がします。そのあたりを確認していただくのと、`image_data` の由来がわかるように前後のコードも載せていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 前後のコードも記載させていただきました。